# OpenSAML3 resource not found 'default-config.xml' in OSGi container

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, opensaml, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade to OpenSAML 3 in an OSGi bundle running on Apache Karaf (4.0.5) using opensaml servicemix bundle (`org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml:jar:3.2.0_1`).

A test that parses the SAML is working so I think I'm on the right track. However, if I install the bundle on Karaf I get a **"resource not found"** error when it's trying to load `default-config.xml`.

```
2016-06-21 16:29:10,477 | INFO  | ool-120-thread-1 | InitializationService            | 388 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml - 3.2.0.1 | Initializing OpenSAML using the Java Services API
2016-06-21 16:29:10,478 | DEBUG | ool-120-thread-1 | InitializationService            | 388 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml - 3.2.0.1 | Initializing module initializer implementation: org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer
2016-06-21 16:29:10,487 | DEBUG | ool-120-thread-1 | XMLConfigurator                  | 388 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml - 3.2.0.1 | XMLObjectProviderRegistry did not exist in ConfigurationService, will be created
2016-06-21 16:29:10,488 | DEBUG | ool-120-thread-1 | ractXMLObjectProviderInitializer | 388 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml - 3.2.0.1 | Loading XMLObject provider configuration from resource 'default-config.xml'
2016-06-21 16:29:10,489 | ERROR | ool-120-thread-1 | ractXMLObjectProviderInitializer | 388 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml - 3.2.0.1 | Problem loading configuration resource
org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurationException: Resource not found
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:54)[388:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml:3.2.0.1]
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(XMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:45)[388:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml:3.2.0.1]
    at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:56)[388:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml:3.2.0.1]
```

`AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer` is loading the resource as follows (`resource` is `default-config.xml`):

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource)
```

`default-config.xml` is located in the root of the (opensaml) jar which makes me wonder if that's the reason it cannot be found.

I'm using the `maven-bundle-plugin` in my project and on top of the dependency and various uses of opensaml classes I provided explicit imports (`Import-Package`) for the following packages:

```
org.opensaml.core.xml.config,
org.opensaml.saml.config,
org.opensaml.xmlsec.config,
```

Is there anything I am missing in my bundle's manifest or elsewhere to make this work? I presume the opensaml bundle released by servicemix itself should be working as is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to the "resource not found" issue but it's a hack more than anything...

After stumbling across the SO post [Better handling of Thread Context ClassLoader in OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198928/better-handling-of-thread-context-classloader-in-osgi) I adapted my code to set the classloader of the `InitializationService` before calling it, the XML in question is now found during initialization.

```
    // adapt TCCL
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader loader = thread.getContextClassLoader();
    thread.setContextClassLoader(InitializationService.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
        InitializationService.initialize();
    } finally {
        // reset TCCL
        thread.setContextClassLoader(loader);
    }
```

However, I've noticed that the SPI config `org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer` in my bundle does not get loaded and I have not figured out a proper fix for that yet. My current workaround is explicitly calling the init methods of initializers I need:

- `org.opensaml.saml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer`
- `org.opensaml.saml.config.SAMLConfigurationInitializer`
- `org.opensaml.xmlsec.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer`

Mind that the following are required as well but get initialized per default (because of SPI config `org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer` in opensaml bundle - which does get loaded):

- `org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer`
- `org.opensaml.core.xml.config.GlobalParserPoolInitializer`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problems, but with Apache Felix OSGI.
With "resource not found" you are right, as I found in OSGI environment uses many ClassLoaders for bundles, but SAML v3 framework loads resources like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
//And same in InitializationService
ServiceLoader<Initializer> serviceLoader = getServiceLoader();
Iterator iter = serviceLoader.iterator();
```

Your solution works for initialization, but for me, when I trying to Sign message, or validate, still have this problem, so I replace resource loading with bundle ClassLoader everywhere:

```
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundleContext.getBundle().adapt(BundleWiring.class);
ClassLoader loader = bundleWiring.getClassLoader();
```

The second problem is problem with opensaml servicemix bundle, it contains service initializers references only for CORE module, you can find it in META-INF/services, I solve this problem by initializing this services in my custom initializer.

I was trying to contact with servicemix developers to indicate them that problem but unsuccessfully.